# Prove that $n! > 2^n$ for $n\geq 4$ (solution question)

Tags: induction

I'm having a hard time figuring out a part of the solution
So I'm trying to prove 
$n! > 2^n$ for $n \geq 4$

and the solution is attached as a picture[image]

I'm confused as to what happens from the solution line 2 to 3. I don't get the "since k >= 4 and so $k + 1 \geq 2$" reasoning. How does k + 1 become 2 and why does the inequality go from > to $\geq$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $k \ge 4$, then $k+1 \ge 5$ and in particular $k+1 \ge 2$. The switch from $>$ to $\ge$ wasn't really necessary. In fact if $k \ge 4$ then $k+1 > 2$.

Comment: why does it become 2 and not 4?

Comment: The idea is to show that $(k+1) \cdot k! > 2\cdot 2^k$. This is true if both $k! > 2^k$ and $k+1 > 2$.